# rationality of Fano 3fold $X_{18}$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, projective-geometry, birational-geometry

I need a reference for an explicit proof of the rationality of the Fano 3-fold $X_{18}$. By explicit I mean by a sequence of explicit birational transformations.

Thank you!

Comment: Have you looked into Iskovskikh classification paper? I think he uses the double projection from a line to relate this threefold to something simpler.

Comment: @Sasha: thank you, which is exactly the paper that you mention?

Comment: it makes sense to start with this http://www.springer.com/us/book/9783540614685 book, you will find there a reference (and probably also a construction).